# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, gradle

I'm working on an App in Android Studio, past 10 minutes I ran it and it works, but now I got this. I got  and error at

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompact-v7:28.0.0'

Can you please tell me what should I modify?

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.quizonwheels.quizonwheels"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AwesomeSplash library is using v23 of the support library.

Change the implementation to:

```
implementation ('com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```